# Variables in a Postgres view?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a view in Postgres which queries a master table (150 million rows) and retrieves data from the prior day (a function which returns SELECT yesterday; it was the only way to get the view to respect my partition constraints) and then joins it with two dimension tables. This works fine, but how would I loop through this query in Python? Is there a way to make the date dynamic?

```
for date in date_range('2016-06-01', '2017-07-31'):
    (query from the view, replacing the date with the date in the loop)
```

My workaround was to literally copy and paste the entire view as a huge select statement format string, and then pass in the date in a loop. This worked, but it seems like there must be a better solution to utilize an existing view or to pass in a variable which might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To loop day by day inside the interval on a for loop you could do something like:

```
import datetime

initialDate = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1)
finalDate = datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 31)

for day in range((finalDate - initialDate).days + 1):
    current = (initialDate + datetime.timedelta(days = day)).date()
    print("query from the view, replacing the date with " + current.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Replacing the print with the call to your query. If the dates are strings you can do something like:

```
initialDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("06/01/2016", '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I meant how can I edit a view to be dynamic in Postgres. I have a view I want to query from in a Python loop, so I select from that view where the date is equal to the date in my loop

Comment: If you could update your question to include the view code and the kind of return you are expecting from it, maybe I could help you.